# The force exerted on a pulley in a atwood machine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

There was a question on my test where I had to find the force exerted on pulley by the string in an atwood machine.
[image: Full diagram]

From the 2 masses I got:
$$
4g - T = 4a      \\
T - 3g = 3a      \\
a = \frac{g}{7}  \\
T = \frac{24}{7}g
$$

I took the 2 masses and the string as 1 system. There are only 2 forces acting on the system: the force the pulley exerts on the string ($P$) and the weight of the system ($W$). Also the system is accelerating downwards at $\frac{g}{7}$.
[image: A diagram of the string+masses system]

So I tried this:
$$
W - P = m \cdot a            \\
7g - P = 7 \cdot \frac{g}{7} \\
P = 6g
$$

But according to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/108424/234706) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/578032/234706) the force should be $2T$ (which $=\frac{48}{7}g$). Therefore, at least 1 of my assumptions must be wrong. Which one of my assumptions is wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centre of mass of the whole system is *not* accelerating at $\frac g 7$.

The $4$ kg mass is accelerating downwards at $\frac g 7$ but the $3$ kg mass is accelerating upwards at $\frac g 7$. So the acceleration of the centre of mass is

$\displaystyle \frac {4 \times \frac g 7 - 3 \times \frac g 7}{4+3} = \frac g {49}$

and so

$\displaystyle P = 7g - \frac {7g} {49} = \frac {48}{7}g$

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. When I found how the centre of mass was moving (to incorrectly prove that its moving at $\frac{g}{7}$), I forgot to divide by the sum of the masses. That fully solves my problem thanks.